# How can i use or where query with relation table column in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, database, eloquent, relationship

**I want to use query for search where doctor location or clinic address from clinic table that joined with the doctors id's foreign key but using with i can able to get data but for clinic address the error is coming like this :-**

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'clinicaddress' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `doctors` where `city` LIKE %test% or `state` LIKE %test% or `country` LIKE %test% or `address1` LIKE %test% or `address2` LIKE %test% or `clinicaddress` LIKE %test% and `status` = 1)

**query is shown like below:-**

```
$doctor = Doctor::with('clinics')->where('city','LIKE','%'.$request->locationsearch.'%')
            ->orwhere('state','LIKE','%'.$request->locationsearch.'%')
            ->orwhere('country','LIKE','%'.$request->locationsearch.'%')
            ->orwhere('address1','LIKE','%'.$request->locationsearch.'%')
            ->orwhere('address2','LIKE','%'.$request->locationsearch.'%')
            ->orwhere('clinicaddress','LIKE','%'.$request->locationsearch.'%')
            ->where('status','=','1')->get();
```

*Doctor Model code is like this:-*

```
protected $fillable = [
        'username','email','firstname','lastname','phoneno','password','gender','dob','profileimage',
        'biography','address1','address2','city','state','country','pincode','service','specialization',
        'general_cons_price','videocallprice','voicecallprice','status',
    ];

public function clinics(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Clinic','dr_id');
    }
```

*Clinic Model code is like this:-*

```
public function doctor(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Doctor','dr_id');
    }
```

*so please tell me how can i use the orwhere query in the same variable with relationship.*

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a `whereHas`.

You could do something like `->whereHas('clinic', function ($query) use ($addressVariable) { $query->where('address', $addrerssVariable); })`

You can also do `->orWhereHas` in your case if you need the or. You should be mindful of how you're using `orWhere` with `where`. You may need to group them differently for it to do what you really want. For example `->where('thingOne', true)->where(function ($query) { $query->where('thingTwo', false)->orWhere('thingThree', false); })`.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you true way, i think you should use belongs to many relationship. Like this;
The doctor may work in more than one clinic. And more than one doctor can work in a clinic.

Pivot Table;

```
 Schema::create('clinic_doctor', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('clinic_id')->constrained('clinics');
        $table->foreignId('doctor_id')->constrained('doctors');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Doctor Model;

```
public function clinics(){
   return $this->belongsToMany(Clinic::class, 'clinic_doctor');
{
```

Clinic Model;

```
public function doctors(){
   return $this->belongsToMany(Doctor::class, 'clinic_doctor');
}
```

Your query;

```
$doctors = Doctor::whereHas('clinics',function($clinics) use ($request) {
    $clinics->where('city','like','%'.$request->city.'%');
})->get();
```